# Microsoft SQL for PHP driver

Tags: iis, php, sql

I am running a W2K3 x64 server with IIS 7 + FastCGI + PHP 5.3 (x64)
I have trouble geting the SQL for php driver to work. It seems it doesn't get loaded, but no error is thrown.

I've doublechedked the php.ini a multitude of times and I'm pretty sure I use the right version of the sql for php driver (version 1.1 CTP) and sql native client x64 is installed.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Dumb question: What's phpinfo() say?

Comment: It says nothing about sqlsrv at all, as it weren't loaded. ANd fact is it wasnt.
Later when checking the logs it clearly stated that it failed to load the sqlsrv module due to it being x86 while php was running x64.

Comment: Then there's your answer. ;) Step 1: Check debug output (in this case, phpinfo). Step 2: Check logs. Step 3,to be performed only after steps 1 and 2: Post to serverfault!

Answer (score 1):

Found out and confirmed that the php sql driver won't work with x64 builds of PHP. It works fine with x86 php build on x64 operative systems however.

Comment: that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems caused by msvcrt.dll not being in a directory that the php engine could access.  I solved it coping msvcrt.dll to the php directory for my install.

You might also look at [MSSQL Requirements @ Php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)